# scrape multiple page and put result in one CSV

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

i am a newbie in coding programs, and i start with python. i use it for scraping data from website, online shops to be specific. i want to scrape every page of the result page (with pagination) and put the result url in one csv

this is what i've been trying

```
import selenium
import bs4
from selenium import webdriver
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

myurl = 'https://www.tokopedia.com/p/rumah-tangga/alat-pertukangan/obeng?keyword=obeng&page='
chrome_path = '/home/yoga/Downloads/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

#opening webpage
for number in range(10):
    buka = driver.get(myurl + str(number))

page_source = driver.page_source
soup_this = soup(page_source, "html.parser")
product_links = soup_this.findAll("div",{"class":"product-summary"})

for number2 in range(10):
    filename = "tokopedia" + str(number2) + ".csv"
f = open(filename, "w")
headers = "Link" + "\n"
f.write(headers)

for product in product_links:
    barang = product.a["ng-href"]
    print(barang + "\n")
    f.write(barang + "\n")

f.close()
driver.close()
```

the result that i got in the csv is only for one page. can you guys help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import selenium
import bs4
from selenium import webdriver
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

myurl = 'https://www.tokopedia.com/p/rumah-tangga/alat-pertukangan/obeng?keyword=obeng&page='
chrome_path = '/home/yoga/Downloads/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

filename = "tokopedia.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")
#opening webpage
for number in range(10):
    buka = driver.get(myurl + str(number))

    page_source = driver.page_source
    soup_this = soup(page_source, "html.parser")
    product_links = soup_this.findAll("div",{"class":"product-summary"})


    headers = "Link" + "\n"
    f.write(headers)

    for product in product_links:
        barang = product.a["ng-href"]
        print(barang + "\n")
        f.write(barang + "\n")

f.close()
driver.close()
```

Comment: hey i got result with separated csv files, how can i get it in ONE csv file?